# How to do a specific citation changing a comma to a colon for just one citation

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to do a citation like this "Name (year: page)" but when I use `\citet[page]{<key>}`, LaTeX returns "Name (year, page)". I just want to change the comma to a colon. Is there a way? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why just one citation? What's distinguishing it from the others?

Comment: Do you use the `natbib` citation management package? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shared with us which style you are using, but assuming you use one of the standard `biblatex` styles you can redefine `postnotedelim` to change the delimiter before the postnote (page range).

Usually people who want a colon before the postnote also want to drop the "p."/"pp." prefix before the page range. This is achieved by redefining the `postnote` field format.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addcolon\space}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite[381]{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Sigfridsson and Ryde (1998: 381)]